# How to remove key error when looking up a definition in a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

I am relatively new to python or even programming in general so go easy on me (I'm sure this is a two line fix)

anyways I am supposed to write a program that has a hardcoded dictionary that a user can edit via a menu system.  Everything is working perfectly except for when someone tried to look up, replace, or delete a word and does not enter a word that is already in the dictionary!
How can I change my code so that when they enter something not in the dictionary it just puts them through the loop and asks them to try again?

```
dic={'1':"Steam",'2':"word",'3':"spotify",'4':"smite"}    
menu=int(input("what would you like to do")   
if menu==2:
    print(dic[input("what do you want to look up")])
```

Thank you for your time on answering my super basic question!

Comment: Updated answer to avoid double convert

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
dic={'1':"Steam",'2':"word",'3':"spotify",'4':"smite"}  
while True:
    menu = raw_input("what would you like to do: ")                                                                                                                                   
    if menu in dic:
         break
```

Just use an infinite loop until an option matchs a dict key.

Comment: This way you get other errors when user enters a value that cannot be converted to integer. Actually, there is no need to convert it to int and back to str. Also, one can use `value = dic.get(menu, 'not in dic')` where the second argument is the default value if the key `menu` is not present in the dictionary. Then you do not need the `if` and the `value` can always be printed.

Comment: Thanks for point that out @pepr , i'm going to update the post to avoid double convert by using raw_input

Comment: Also, the tag is python-3.x -- the `input` should be used instead of `raw_input`.